# How to deploy additional fonts in cloud foundry windows cell

Tags: cloud-foundry, cloudfoundry-uaa

I have a need to deploy additional fonts in my cloud foundry windows cell.  Any clue on how I can go about with the same.

thanks
Lokesh

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [BOSH release](https://bosh.io/docs/windows/) that has a job whose role is to install the fonts. Once you have done that, you can create a [runtime config](https://bosh.io/docs/runtime-config/) that applies that job to the windows cells.